# How do I create completely new objects without any interference with old objects in python?

Tags: python, oop

I am very new to python facing this problem defined below.
I am creating several graphs from this class named "Node"

```
class Node(object):
    label = ""
    nexts = ()
    prevs = ()
    pos_tag = ""
    visited = False    # black = False (unexplored),  white = True (explored)
    score = 0
```

My Graph generating function is

```
    # Generating the graph
    def generate_graph(self, text, startnode, endnode):
        sentences = self.convert_to_sentences(text)
        sentences = [sentence.replace(",","") for sentence in sentences]
        while(" ." in sentences):
            sentences.remove(" .")

        length = len(sentences)
        self.START = startnode
        self.END = endnode
        G = nx.Graph()
        G.add_node(self.START)
        G.add_node(self.END)
        for i in range(0, length):
            words = sentences[i].split()
            sent_size = len(words)
            v = [Node() for i in range(sent_size)]
            for j in range(0, sent_size):
                label = words[j]
                tag = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(label))[0][1]

                if self.exists_node(self.START, label, tag):
                    v[j] = self.get_existing_node(self.START, label, tag)
                else:
                    v[j] = self.create_new_node(label, tag)
                    G.add_node(v[j])
                if j==0:
                    tup = (v[j],)
                    self.START.nexts = self.START.nexts + tup
                    G.add_edge(self.START, v[j])
                if v[j].label == ".":
                    self.add_edge(v[j], self.END)
                    G.add_edge(v[j], self.END)
                if not self.exists_edge(v[j-1], v[j]):
                    self.add_edge(v[j-1], v[j])
                    G.add_edge(v[j-1], v[j])

        Nodes = []
        graph_size, Nodes = self.graph_size(self.START)
        for i in range(0, graph_size):
            print(Nodes[i].label, Nodes[i].pos_tag)
            leng = len(Nodes[i].nexts)
            for x in range(0, leng):
                print(Nodes[i].nexts[x].label, Nodes[i].nexts[x].pos_tag)
            print(" ")


        #nx.draw(G)
        paths = self.find_paths(G, self.START, self.END)
        return paths
```

I am calling this graph generating function several times to generate several graphs, First graph is generated really fine, but 2nd and subsequent graphs contain edges from preceeding graphs i.e. It already contains the state of the preceeding graph and just adds new edges on it.

Consider this example of word level graph generation from sentences:-

Sentence-1 :- Merlyn is a big cat.

Sentence 1 creates graph having an edge from **Merlyn->is** which is perfectly fine.

Sentence-2:- Merlyn used to drink Milk.

Sentence 2 creates graph having 2 edges from **Merlyn->used** and **Merlyn->is**

Sentence 2 should have only single edge **Merlyn->used**
Thanks in advance

Comment: All your `Node` fields are static, could that be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This question would be dramatically improved (and easier to answer) if you edit it so it becomes an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

All your nodes variables should be instance level variables instead of class level variables.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = ""
        self.nexts = ()
        self.prevs = ()
        self.pos_tag = ""
        self.visited = False
        self.score = 0
```

Comment: Tried this thing, but it didn't work. Can it be related to the mutable nature of the Node class ?